# Align the columns of two tables in html

Tags: html, google-chrome

I know this has been asked a few times but none of the answers targets the theoretical problem behind it and none of them has worked for me (if this is solvable, which I am not sure of).

I have two tables. Yes, they need to be tables and no, I cannot merge them. One of them has a multiple column value of the other (see the sample code). Being this so, the common dividers of both columns are never aligned in Chrome. I mention chrome because it works on firefox though, but has to work on chrome.

Redefining the `padding` of cells to 0, split into `thead` and `tbody`... doesn't work. Of course it works if put the same amount of columns in both tables. Any constructive comment is hightly appreciated since Im a bit desperate. Thanks!

```html
<table style="table-layout: fixed; width: 590px; height: 25px; border-collapse:collapse;
  border-spacing:0;">
  <tr>
    <td style="border-collapse: collapse;  border: 1px solid #ddd"></td>
    <td style="border: 1px solid #ddd"></td>
    <td style="border: 1px solid #ddd"></td>
    <td style="border: 1px solid #ddd"></td>
    <td style="border: 1px solid #ddd"></td>
    <td style="border: 1px solid #ddd"></td>
    <td style="border: 1px solid #ddd"></td>
    <td style="border: 1px solid #ddd"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
<table style="table-layout: fixed; width: 590px; height: 25px; border-collapse:collapse;
  border-spacing:0;">
  <tr>
    <td style="border-style: solid dotted solid solid; border-color: #ddd; border-width: 1px;">
    <td style="border-style: solid dotted; border-color: #ddd; border-width: 1px;">
    <td style="border-style: solid dotted; border-color: #ddd; border-width: 1px;">
    <td style="border-style: solid solid solid dotted; border-color: #ddd; border-width: 1px;">
    <td style="border-style: solid dotted solid solid; border-color: #ddd; border-width: 1px;">
    <td style="border-style: solid dotted; border-color: #ddd; border-width: 1px;">
    <td style="border-style: solid dotted; border-color: #ddd; border-width: 1px;">
    <td style="border-style: solid solid solid dotted; border-color: #ddd; border-width: 1px;">
    <td style="border-style: solid dotted solid solid; border-color: #ddd; border-width: 1px;">
    <td style="border-style: solid dotted; border-color: #ddd; border-width: 1px;">
    <td style="border-style: solid dotted; border-color: #ddd; border-width: 1px;">
    <td style="border-style: solid solid solid dotted; border-color: #ddd; border-width: 1px;">
    <td style="border-style: solid dotted solid solid; border-color: #ddd; border-width: 1px;">
    <td style="border-style: solid dotted; border-color: #ddd; border-width: 1px;">
    <td style="border-style: solid dotted; border-color: #ddd; border-width: 1px;">
    <td style="border-style: solid solid solid dotted; border-color: #ddd; border-width: 1px;">
    <td style="border-style: solid dotted solid solid; border-color: #ddd; border-width: 1px;">
    <td style="border-style: solid dotted; border-color: #ddd; border-width: 1px;">
    <td style="border-style: solid dotted; border-color: #ddd; border-width: 1px;">
    <td style="border-style: solid solid solid dotted; border-color: #ddd; border-width: 1px;">
    <td style="border-style: solid dotted solid solid; border-color: #ddd; border-width: 1px;">
    <td style="border-style: solid dotted; border-color: #ddd; border-width: 1px;">
    <td style="border-style: solid dotted; border-color: #ddd; border-width: 1px;">
    <td style="border-style: solid solid solid dotted; border-color: #ddd; border-width: 1px;">
    <td style="border-style: solid dotted solid solid; border-color: #ddd; border-width: 1px;">
    <td style="border-style: solid dotted; border-color: #ddd; border-width: 1px;">
    <td style="border-style: solid dotted; border-color: #ddd; border-width: 1px;">
    <td style="border-style: solid solid solid dotted; border-color: #ddd; border-width: 1px;">
    <td style="border-style: solid dotted solid solid; border-color: #ddd; border-width: 1px;">
    <td style="border-style: solid dotted; border-color: #ddd; border-width: 1px;">
    <td style="border-style: solid dotted; border-color: #ddd; border-width: 1px;">
    <td style="border-style: solid solid solid dotted; border-color: #ddd; border-width: 1px;">
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Have you tried `border-collapse: collapse;` on the table?

Comment: could you post an example of what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Kind of solved the problem although Im not completely satisfied. Fix the tds width of both tables, and then play around with the total widths of the tables until it matches nicely.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the way your `table`s are designed.

Both tables are set to `590px` so ideally they both should take up the same space.

However you didn't account for `cellspacing` and `cellpadding`.

In order to design these 2 tables to align perfectly you need to set the `width` of each `td` and as well as account for `cellspacing`.

If you divide the first table properly each td comes up to `73.75px` and the second to `18.4375`

However the second table has more `cellspacing` due to more number of columns.

If you calculate correctly and account for `cellspacing` it should solve your problem.

Hope this will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Kind of solved the problem although Im not completely satisfied. 
1. Fix the tds width of both tables
2. Play around with the total widths of the tables until it matches nicely.